# A little help using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Can anyone link me to some Symfony resources, they are hard to find. I am having a little trouble understanding how to use it correctly. Like with CodeIgniter to use the security helper you would load it doing this:

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

And you would use its functions you would do something like this:

```
$data = $this->input->xss_clean($data);
```

But with Smyfony to redirect someone to a 404 page, you need to use the sfAction class and the redirect404() api. So could anyone explain or link me a good tutorial?

Comment: If you want resources about Symfony look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108861/where-can-i-find-more-documentation-tutorials-about-symfony

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you set aside a few hours and read through the [Practical Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/) tutorial. It goes through all the basics from project start to end.

Symfony, although a great framework, has a steep learning curve. This tutorial really helps you understand how it works, from the basics to more advanced stuff.

Comment: Ya, I have gotten through about half of it, its just I would prefer if it was a blog tutorial, it feels so.. Out of spirit, its like a programming tutorial that does not use "Hello World!"..

Answer (score 0):

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_skipping_to_another_action (scroll down a few paragraphs)

**Using**

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction

You have access to a number of 404 redirection methods (redirect404, forward404, forward404If, forward404Unless) which are detailed on the link above.  You have access to all of these methods from within your actions:

```
public function executeAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404();
}
```

I would recommend using forward404 instead of redirect404 as the latter will push the redirection back to the browser and show your user the 404 page's URL instead of the URL they attempted to access.

**Configuring**

You can configure the module and action that should be executed when a 404 is triggered in your application's `config/settings.yml` like this:

```
all:
  .actions:
    error_404_module:       my_module   # To be called when a 404 error is raised
    error_404_action:       my_action   # Or when the requested URL doesn't match any route
```

***Update:***

For general information on Symfony check out the three books they have available online: http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/1_4/, 'Practical Symfony' being a great place to get started.  There is also a complete API reference available: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/.

Comment: Was just using the 404 as an example, but thank you for the link, very helpful.

Comment: @Dr Hydralisk: Ah, missed that.  I've updated my answer with a few resource links, hope that helps.